# Compiling software in cygwin requires cygwin libraries to run

Tags: gcc, build, cygwin

I have just compiled some software in cygwin and all went well, except when I tried to run it on a different machine it required some cygwin specific libraries .dll's, is there anyway I can build this in with the software so it can run on third party machines without cygwin installed? Im trying to be generic with the question so the answer will suit other people facing the same or similar problem so sorry for the lack of detail on the software etc. (sgminer)

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executable file generated using gcc under cygwin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143629/executable-file-generated-using-gcc-under-cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

Not only is this a duplicate, as Paul R point out, it's also an FAQ on the Cygwin site.

From "[How do I compile a Win32 executable that doesn't use Cygwin?](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.programming.win32-no-cygwin)"

> The compilers provided by the mingw-gcc, mingw64-i686-gcc, and
>   mingw64-x86_64-gcc packages link against standard Microsoft DLLs
>   instead of Cygwin. This is desirable for native Windows programs that
>   don't need a UNIX emulation layer.
>
> This is not to be confused with 'MinGW' (Minimalist GNU for Windows),
>   which is a completely separate effort. That project's home page is
>   http://www.mingw.org/index.shtml.