# Linux executable on cygwin terminal

Tags: linux, windows, unix, cygwin

Let me tell you my problem. I've a shell script which execute a Linux executable. I don't have access to the source code of this exe.

When I run the script on the Linux machine, there is no problem.
But, if I try to run the script on my Windows laptop, using cygwin, I have the error "cannot execute binary file".

There is any solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: You need to tell us what the executable is.

Comment: informations extracted from command "file" : ELF 32-bit LSB executable for GNU/Linux 2.6.9

Answer (score 3):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4144536/5704102:

"... Cygwin is a compatibility layer, which aims to implement as much as possible of the POSIX and Linux APIs within Windows. This means that programs have to be compiled specifically for Cygwin ..."

Answer (score 0):

What does this script look like? Is it a bash script? If so, you may want to try `sh <scriptfile>` in Cygwin. If this doesn't work, and it is a bash script, make sure you have `sh.exe`. Type `sh` and hit tab twice to check.

Another potential issue if it is a bash script is that you don't have something installed that Cygwin requires to run the script. Make sure all the commands the script is trying to run will work. If not, you may have to run the Cygwin installer and install whatever is needed to run the script.

Also, you may want to check permissions.

If the file has an `exe` extension, it SHOULD work on Windows unless it was compiled for 64 bit architecture and you're running a 32 bit OS. Otherwise, you could be missing some `.dll` files that the executable relies on.

Edit:

If this is the contents of your script:

```
echo START
/oper/file.exe
```

then it's likely you have the incorrect path. Cygwin paths typically start with `/cygdrive/c/` in Windows. Go to where the file exists and type `pwd` to get the correct path, then modify your script accordingly.

Comment: Yeah it's a bash script. So i call the script with sh command, and i've tried with sh executable.exe to run it, but there is the same issue

Comment: The file has the `exe` extension? If it does, then it probably is not a bash script. If you open the file in a text editor what does it look like?

Comment: my script is a bash script. But this script try to run the executable with exe extension.

Comment: What executable? sh.exe? Could you edit your question to show me exactly what the command is you're trying to run and what the name of the file you're trying to run? Also, posting the contents of the file you're trying to run could be helpful.

Comment: Go to where that file exists, type `pwd` then edit the script to point to the correct path.

Comment: i'm into the correct folder. Script is in /oper directory

Comment: If you're running this through Cygwin, you have the incorrect path. It will probably start with `/cygdrive/c/`

Comment: yeah i've written a reduced path here but in my computer the complete path is /cygdrive/c/Users/jb/oper (which is written also in the Script.sh file)

Comment: And what happens when you put that full path in the script? Does it still not work?

Comment: It prints "cannot execute binary file"

Comment: Do you have permissions to run the file? Have you tried running Cygwin as administrator? Maybe try `chmod 777 /cygdrive/c/Users/jb/oper/file.exe`.

Comment: Yes I've permissions to run it

Comment: What happens when you try opening the file in the Windows GUI?

Comment: it is crashing when i try opening in Windows

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Where did this executable file come from that the script is trying to run?

Comment: No error message appears. this exe is come from a soft which was developped for linux plateform. And I try to developped a script which run it automatically (goal of the script)

Comment: Well, i'was just trying to run it on Mac, and i've the same error message

Comment: If it was compiled for Linux then it will only run on Linux. You need to compile it for the appropriate platform.

Comment: that's why cygwin cannot open it. Ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Content of Script.sh in oper folder :

```
echo START
/cygdrive/c/Users/jo/oper/file.exe
```

In Cygwin terminal (in the right folder):

```
sh Script.sh
```

(Path updated)