# Compile using Cygwin without cygwin dependency

Tags: compilation, cygwin

-mno-cygwin compiler parameter doesn't exist.

I tried to use '-static', but then compiler can't find installed -lpng

Answer (score 2):

You need to cross compile it. Run `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`, included in package `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++`, in cygwin64 to cross compile a native windows 64bit executable. It is similar if you are in cygwin or to compile a 32bit executable.

However, without cygwin compatibility layer, a program using POSIX APIs cannot be compiled. If your program needs POSIX APIs, you have to compile with cygwin dependency.

Reference [Executable file generated using GCC under cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143629/executable-file-generated-using-gcc-under-cygwin)